# Auth0 and Grails 3 spring security plugin

Tags: grails, spring-security, auth0

Is there any documentation on how to implement auth0 with a grails 3 application using the grails spring security plugin? We're able to find some documentation for regular java mvc apps but not for a grails 3 app that is using the spring security plugin with RoleGroup security. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The options currently available in terms of what has been published for Grails 3 with [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) are:

- [Auth0 Grails 3 MVC Sample](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-grails3-mvc-sample)
- [Auth0 Grails 3 Spring Security MVC Sample](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-grails3-spring-security-mvc-sample)

We do not have any samples that leverage the Spring Security Plugin itself, instead handling the integration out of bands of the need for the plugin. Hope this clarifies what is currently published, and you are able to work with these options.

**Disclaimer** - I work for [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) and am the author of both samples, and underlying Java libraries upon which the samples have dependencies.

Comment: Thanks.  Has anything been updated on this in the last seven months?  The spring security plugin relies on an authentication provider. Is there an implementation of an auth0 authentication provider that can be used and store the principal as an instance of a User and not a jwt?  Or what options are there with this?

Comment: Both samples were updated last month (November 2017) to use Lock v11 - other minor changes included ensuring the configuration defaulted to setting base64 encoded client secrets to false (Auth0 changed its default behaviour some time ago) and bumping minor versions of dependencies. No further changes have been needed / requested.

Comment: @pd-611 - I've got a pending pull request in for the Auth0 Grails 3 Spring Security MVC Example repo that gets it working again for current Auth0/Grails. I'll be working on a plugin that integrates with the Grails Spring Security Core plugin over the next week.